# BlueCap Kit BLE imlementation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am Using swift to connect to a peripheral via BLE and collect data in an iOS app.   The wrapper I use was originally written by Troy Stribling.  https://github.com/troystribling/BlueCap.

I am having trouble adopting my device characteristics to match the style he is using.  The app works to the point where it discover devices but when I try to subscribe to the characteristics to collect data it fails.  Here is a sample of my ViewController.swift code. Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
// discover services and characteristics

    let peripheralDiscoveredFuture = peripheralConnectFuture.flatmap{(peripheral, connectionEvent) -> Future<Peripheral> in
        if peripheral.state == .Connected {
            return peripheral.discoverPeripheralServices([serviceUUID])
    } else {
        let promise = Promise<Peripheral>()
        promise.success(peripheral)
        return promise.future
           }
    } // end of flatmap
    peripheralDiscoveredFuture.onSuccess {peripheral in
        if let service = peripheral.service(serviceUUID) {
            self.HaIdCharacteristic = service.characteristic(hearingAidUUID)
            self.HaBatteryCharacteristic = service.characteristic(batteryUUID)
            self.HaSideCharacteristic = service.characteristic(sideUUID)
            self.SsiNextCharacteristic = service.characteristic(ssiNextUUID)
        }
    }
    // get the characteristic value

    let readEnabledFuture = peripheralDiscoveredFuture.flatmap {__ -> Future<Characteristic> in
        if let HaIdCharacteristic = self.HaIdCharacteristic {
            return HaIdCharacteristic.read(10.0)
        }else {
            let promise = Promise<Characteristic>()
            promise.failure(CentralError.enabledCharacteristicNotFound)
            return promise.future
           }
        }
    readEnabledFuture.onSuccess {characteristic in
        self.updateEnabled(characteristic)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you have the correct characteristic UUID?  You can use an application like [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) to double check.

Comment: excellent suggestion.  I am on this right now.  It appears some of my devices don't have services turned on correctly.I will keep you posted.

Comment: Sure thing, if you decide not to use BlueCap you can take a look at my implementation for code to connect to a Bluno, might be very similar to what you are looking for.
Here is the repo:  https://github.com/FredLoh/BluetoothResearchProject

Comment: The project you suggested looks a lot easier to follow.  I may switch to using the project above.  At some point a person has to cut their losses and move on  I am at that breaking point with the BlueCap code.  Thank you!!

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to fork it and use it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is working well.  After getting a hint from @SnarfSnarf, I used a sniffer app to find my UUID's.  I had a couple of problems:
1.  My devices were not configured correctly.
2.  The UUID for the characteristics were incorrect.

Once I fixed the above I started collecting data.  Thank you!!